# pinging over interface fails, pinging over ip address of interface succeeds

Tags: ping

I often use the `ping -I` option to test if an interface forwards packets correctly.

A Raspberry Pi 3 has an interface named eth1. It is a USB to female ethernet connector.
I manually configured this interface with the ip address 172.22.22.1/24.

When I perform `ping -I eth1 example.com` I receive a "Destination host not reachable" message.
However when I issue `ping -I 172.22.22.1 example.com`, the ping command replies correct.

I am curious why the results differ. Can anybody explain?

Comment: Curious, do you have outgoing rules defined in iptables/ufw. This could cause this behavior.

Comment: To be sure of *anything* you should provide your current network state with these commands: `ip -br link; ip -4 -br address; ip -4 route; ip -4 rule` as well as (for a few hints) `ip -4 neigh` after having tried both kinds of ping. Of course the effect of both kinds of ping is different but without seeing the configuration first, it's not worth trying to explain an hypothetical cause.